# Как отправлять нужные поля в зависимости от того есть они или нет?

Tags: javascript

```js
onSubmit() {
        let body = {
            name: this.form.value.cityName,
            type: 3,
            parentData: [
                {"glob_id": this.form.value.regionName.region_id},
                {"glob_id": this.form.value.districtName.glob_id},
                {"glob_id": this.form.value.areaName.glob_id}
            ],
            type_id: this.form.value.typeObj.id

        };
```

В parentData у есть массив обьектов. В каждого есть свойство glob_id с значением. Обьект body отправляется на сервер, но есть проблема, если одно из значений glob_id не будет заполнено, то запрос не выполнится (в массиве отправляется пустой обьект и сервер возвращает ошибку). 
Как мне переделать код так, чтобы если одно из значений glob_id будет пустым, то не отправлять этот обьект?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как мне переделать код так, чтобы если одно из значений glob_id будет пустым, то не отправлять этот обьект?

Вот так:

```js
let body = {
  name: 'cityName',
  type: 3,
  parentData: [{
      "glob_id": 'regionName.region_id'
    },
    {
      "glob_id": 'districtName.glob_id'
    },
    {
      "glob_id": 'areaName.glob_id'
    },
    {
      "glob_id": null
    },
    {
      "gloN_id": 'areaName.glob_id'
    }
  ],
  type_id: 'typeObj.id'

};
// Проверка если glob_id есть и не null можно сделать любую другую проверку
body.parentData = body.parentData.filter(v => v.hasOwnProperty('glob_id') && v.glob_id !== null)

console.log(body.parentData);
```

Answer (score 0):

В качестве решения могу посоветовать два варианта:

1. Значения "glob_id" устанавливать null, но это зависит от бэкенда, как он написан, если все нормально, то он будет их фильтровать.
2. Перед отправкой данных проводить фильтрацию значений:

```js
body.parentData = body.parentData.filter(v => v.glob_id.length)
```

3. Чтобы совсем не отправлять объект - просто сделать валидацию:

```js
if(body.parentData.find(v => v.glob_id.length)) sendData();
```